# Configuring module with service result

Tags: angular

I have an (injectable, singleton) service that can load the configuration from server

```
export class ConfigService {
  //.. some properties
  private static instance: ConfigService;

  constructor( //.. some dependecies, including Http) {
    if (ConfigService.instance) {
        return ConfigService.instance;
    }

    ConfigService.instance = this;
  }

  init(){
    //..  load config file from server
  }
}
```

I have it run on app init

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [InnerModule],
  providers: [ //...
    { 
       provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
       useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.init(), 
       deps: [ConfigService], 
       multi: true 
    }
 ]
)
export class AppModule {}
```

Now, the inner module needs to load a library module, that can be configured with a `.forRoot` call that takes a configuration object

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LibraryModule.forRoot({
            colors: //.. colors provided by configuration service
        })
    ],
})
export class InnerModule { }
```

The problem is that the module loading is done *before* the initializer is run, so I cannot use the config there.

Is there a way to postpone the module loading until I can guarantee that the configuration is loaded?

---

What I basically need is to be able to configure a library which can only be configured via `.forRoot` with some data that is only available at runtime, and needs to be loaded from the server.

Comment: This is a bad pratice. Try to solve it in another way.

Comment: I know. And the other way is the question :)